# How to include non-python modules in python scripts while converting it to exe?

Tags: python, ffmpeg

As far as I know, ffmpeg is not a built-in python module but it comes with moviepy module? (I'm not sure), so in order to use it, we need to manually install it. However, I installed it on my computer and my program works perfectly, but then I thought about converting my program to an executable file so that I can show it to my friends, once I did that the program lost functionality, and it turned out that whomever I send the program to should have ffmpeg on their computers! How am I going to fix this?

**Note**: on the os.environ line, I'm giving it the path where the ffmpeg exe file is in it.

**Note**: I used both pyinstaller and cx_freeze but none worked.

The program is a GUI Youtube mp3 downloader (you can use it if you have time), it downloads a video.mp4 first, converts the mp4 to mp3, and then deletes the mp4.

I appreciate any help, I have been looking for solutions from all over the internet, nothing helped so far, any suggestions are welcomed, or if there is any other way I can download MP3s from a youtube video? Thanks in advance.

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from pytube import YouTube
from tkinter import messagebox
import os
os.environ["IMAGEIO_FFMPEG_EXE"] = r"C:\Users\Totenkopf\Downloads\test\ffmpeg"
from moviepy.video.io.VideoFileClip import VideoFileClip

def space():
    space = Label(text="", bg="black")
    space.grid()

Folder_Name = ""

def open_location():
    global Folder_Name
    Folder_Name = filedialog.askdirectory()
    os.chdir(Folder_Name)
    if len(Folder_Name) > 1:
        path_url.config(text=Folder_Name, fg="green")

    else:
        messagebox.showwarning(title="oops", message="No path given!")
        path_url.config(text="Please specify a folder!", fg="red")
    return

def convert_to_mp3():
    if len(url_box.get()) > 1 and "youtube.com" in url_box.get():
        url_error.config(text="")
        root.update()
        if len(Folder_Name) > 1:
            yt = YouTube(url_box.get())
            yt.streams.get_highest_resolution().download(Folder_Name)
            music = yt.streams.first()
            default_filename = music.default_filename
            new_filename = default_filename.split(".")[0]
            mp4 = Folder_Name + fr'/{new_filename}.mp4'
            mp3 = Folder_Name + fr'/{new_filename}.mp3'
            videoclip = VideoFileClip(mp4)
            audioclip = videoclip.audio
            audioclip.write_audiofile(mp3)
            audioclip.close()
            videoclip.close()
            os.system(f' del "{new_filename}.mp4"')
            progress_bar.config(text="Downloaded successfully", fg="green")
        else:
            messagebox.showwarning(title="oops", message="No path given!")
            path_url.config(text="Please specify a folder!", fg="red")

    else:
        messagebox.showwarning(title="oops", message="Wrong URL!")
        url_error.config(text="Try again!", fg="red")



#----------------------------- GUI -------------------------------#

root = Tk()
root.title("Youtube Downloader")
root.geometry("350x400")
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.config(bg="black")

space()
space()
space()
space()
space()

url_label = Label(root, text="Enter video / playlist URL", bg="black", fg="white", font=("jost", 9, "bold"))
url_label.grid()

EntryVar = StringVar()
url_box = Entry(root, width=50, textvariable=EntryVar)
url_box.grid()

url_error = Label(root, text="", fg="red", bg="black", font=("jost", 9, "bold"))
url_error.grid()

space()

path_label = Label(root, text="Save the video file", bg="black", fg="white", font=("jost", 9, "bold"))
path_label.grid()

path_btn = Button(root, width=11, height=2, bg="#CC1B25", fg="white", text="Choose Path", command=open_location)
path_btn.grid()

path_url = Label(root, text="", fg="red", bg="black", font=("jost", 9, "bold"))
path_url.grid()

space()

mp3_btn = Button(width=23, height=1, bg="black", fg="white", text=" Download MP3",
                 font=("jost", 11, "bold"), command=convert_to_mp3)
mp3_btn.grid()

space()

progress_bar = Label(root, text="", bg="black", fg="white", font=("jost", 11, "bold"))
progress_bar.grid()

space()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Given that your script includes setting an environment variable to point the script at the location of an ffmpeg executable, you'd have to find a way to: include the executable in a package (that's fairly straightforward if its license allows it) set the environment variable relative to wherever that executable would then end up in the package environment. Once packaged up, something like PyInstaller would still do the job of wrapping all of it in an exe.

Comment: That's what I'm also looking for, I can't find a way through, and the reason why I set that env variable is that the program wouldn't even open without it (telling me ffmpeg doesn't exist). - I have also tried to include in the spec file with adding  --add-binary, also failed

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? Finding out whether ffmpeg can be redistributed like that? Finding out which binaries are required for it to work? Including those binaries in a package so they get installed with the package? Building a package? Adding your own package to a pyinstaller project? There's a lot of steps here, a bit too much for a single question and answer.

Comment: "finding out which binaries are required for it to work and including those binaries in a package so they get installed with the package", I just want it to work on other computers when I send it to someone.

Comment: first you should test .exe on computer without `ffmpeg` (you could uninstall it on your computer) and it should show error message with information what files it can't find - and then you will know what you have to add to file `.spec` - it may need something more than only `ffmpeg`. It may need for example `libmpeg.dll`, `libmp3.dll` etc.

Comment: Okay, I tried adding ffmpeg into spec by puting full path/ffmpeg into binary = [          ], and then while using pyinstaller I used --add-binary "ffmpeg.exe;", is this how things are added to spec? if yes, I have tried that and doesn't work, also, before installing ffmpeg, it gave me errors saying that ffmpeg doesn't exist, after I installed it, the errors are gone.